# MaterialViewPager Scroll Issues

Tags: android

I am using this library:

https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager

My ViewPager looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager
        android:id="@+id/materialViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        app:viewpager_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:viewpager_disableToolbar="false"
        app:viewpager_displayToolbarWhenSwipe="false"
        app:viewpager_enableToolbarElevation="true"
        app:viewpager_headerHeight="200dp"
        app:viewpager_hideToolbarAndTitle="true"
        app:viewpager_pagerTitleStrip="@layout/material_view_pager_pagertitlestrip_newstand"
        app:viewpager_transparentToolbar="false" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When the Fragment is visible, it looks like the following:

Before:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/beforehj03bneut2.png

When I am scrolling down and up again, it looks like this  http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/after5qc2bgdrij.png

How can I fix this scroll issue?

Comment: and this is after:

After:
http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/after5qc2bgdrij.png

Comment: Maybe you should make a github issue and ask your question to the library maintainer